# ChildActivity extends BaseActivity, how to bind views in layout set with LayoutInflater::inflate?

Tags: android, android-layout, butterknife

I'm encountering difficulties trying to successfully inject views with ButterKnife. All the examples I'm seeing assume the `Activity` extends `AppCompatActivity`, and the layout is set with `setContentView()`. My case involves the `Activity` extending a `BaseActivity`, and the layout being set with a `LayoutInflater`'s `inflate()` call:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.drawer_layout) DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

This is the `ChildActivity`:

```
public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.content) FrameLayout content; // content is in the base layout
    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view) RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // content (below) is a FrameLayout in the BaseActivity
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, content);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get an error:

```
Required view 'recycler_view' with ID 2131230798 for field 'recyclerView' 
was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or 
'@Optional' (methods) annotation.
```

So I add `@Nullable` as advised:

```
 @BindView(R.id.recycler_view) @Nullable RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

Another error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v
7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

When I remove that `@Nullable`, I'm back to square one. How do I solve this?

Comment: See this link : https://www.androidhive.info/2017/10/android-working-with-butterknife-viewbinding-library/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and the layout being set with a LayoutInflater's inflate() call

`getLayoutInflater().inflate` returns a whole new View, which needs bound separately than the activity content view. And if you want to use **that view**, you don't need to inflate it, as you just call setContentView with the layout id.

I suggest you use Fragments if you want to do this with a FrameLayout, though.

You would `@BindView` the FrameLayout, then dynamically add Fragments using `getSupportFragmentManager()`
. Whether you use Butterknife in the Fragments is an implementation detail.

At the very least, use an `<include>` tag in the XML instead of a FrameLayout. Your error exists because the Recyclerview is not in the context of the bound instance

Comment: This answer is too short. `View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, content);` followed by `Butterknife.bind(this, v)` is also something I've tried. Same error!

Comment: Because `this` is the Activity, which only has a FrameLayout, DrawerLayout, and Toolbar

Comment: Please see the edit I made to the ChildActivity class. I forgot to add `@BindView(R.id.content) FrameLayout content;` which is a FrameLayout in BaseActivity. Does that change anything?

Comment: Otherwise you're saying that what I'm trying to do is currently not possible with activities? Otherwise no chance I'm switching back to fragments.

Comment: Not really. Your RecyclerView is not in the Activity content view

Comment: Interesting. I've now tried `View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, content)` followed by `setContentView(v)` and finally `ButterKnife.bind(this)`.  Hmmm...

Comment: I suspect the toolbar and DrawerLayout are null, unless that view also includes them

Comment: You're right. The Toolbar and DrawerLayout will be null. I've upvoted this answer since you've given me some valuable information that I was unaware of earlier.